# How to parse a JSON and turn its values into an Array?

Tags: java, json

```
public static void parseProfilesJson(String the_json){
       try {
            JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject(the_json);

            JSONArray nameArray = myjson.names();
            JSONArray valArray = myjson.toJSONArray(nameArray);
            for(int i=0;i<valArray.length();i++)
            {
                String p = nameArray.getString(i) + "," + ValArray.getString(i);
                Log.i("p",p);
            }       

        } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, this sample code will print out the **KEY** of the JSONs, followed by the **VALUES** of the JSONS.

It would print **profiles, john** if the json was like this:

```
{'profiles':'john'}
```

That's cool. That's fine, as I can work with those variables. However, what if the JSON was like this:

```
{'profiles': [{'name':'john', 'age': 44}, {'name':'Alex','age':11}]}
```

In this case, the entire value would be the array. Basically, I just want to grab that array (which is the "value" in this case)...and turn it into an actual array that JAVA could use.  How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Be aware that this wouldn't pass a stricter parser.  JSON requires double-quotes around names and strings (single-quote is not valid).

Comment: Don't worry Jonathon...JSONObject is a JSON.org code provided for JSON parsing in java. What alex put was just example....

Comment: I gave you a point for providing simple code for me to parse my json string.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

for your example:

```
{'profiles': [{'name':'john', 'age': 44}, {'name':'Alex','age':11}]}
```

you will have to do something of this effect:

```
JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject(the_json);
JSONArray the_json_array = myjson.getJSONArray("profiles");
```

this returns the array object.

Then iterating will be as follows:

```
    int size = the_json_array.length();
    ArrayList<JSONObject> arrays = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        JSONObject another_json_object = the_json_array.getJSONObject(i);
            //Blah blah blah...
            arrays.add(another_json_object);
    }

//Finally
JSONObject[] jsons = new JSONObject[arrays.size()];
arrays.toArray(jsons);

//The end...
```

You will have to determine if the data is an array (simply checking that `charAt(0)` starts with `[` character).

Hope this helps.

Comment: What JSON library is being used here? `http://javadox.com/net.minidev/json-smart/1.2/net/minidev/json/JSONObject.html` is it this one?

Comment: I've tried this but Im only able to get ` [{'name':'john', 'age': 44}, {'name':'Alex','age':11}]` is there a way to get only the "name" in an array?

Answer (score 1):

You can prefer quick-json parser to meet your requirement...

quick-json parser is very straight forward, flexible, very fast and customizable. Try this out

[quick-json parser] (https://code.google.com/p/quick-json/)
- quick-json features -

- Compliant with JSON specification (RFC4627)
- High-Performance JSON parser
- Supports Flexible/Configurable parsing approach
- Configurable validation of key/value pairs of any JSON Heirarchy
- Easy to use # Very Less foot print
- Raises developer friendly and easy to trace exceptions
- Pluggable Custom Validation support - Keys/Values can be validated by configuring custom validators as and when encountered
- Validating and Non-Validating parser support
- Support for two types of configuration (JSON/XML) for using quick-json validating parser
- Require JDK 1.5 # No dependency on external libraries
- Support for Json Generation through object serialization
- Support for collection type selection during parsing process

For e.g.

```
JsonParserFactory factory=JsonParserFactory.getInstance();
JSONParser parser=factory.newJsonParser();
Map jsonMap=parser.parseJson(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers in this question assume you have a java object to work with.  I wanted to be able to get values from an arbitrary json structure, one for which I didn't necessarily have the corresponding java object.

My idea is field keys of the form "key":value".  Now, each line of the result contains up to one value which can be put into a list/array.  I also remove json scope delimiters, ie, "[]{},".

My solution makes some assumptions:

1. You use double quotes in your json.
2. The json is pretty formatted.

   ```
   public static String getOnlyJsonValues(String json) {
       json = json.replaceAll("\\{", "");
       json = json.replaceAll("}", "");
       json = json.replaceAll("\\[", "");
       json = json.replaceAll("]", "");
       json = json.replaceAll("\".*?\":", "");
       return json;
   }
   ```

Now, you just need to parse the output into a list of Strings:

```
    public static List<String> parseUniqueValues(String json) {
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        String onlyValues = getOnlyJsonValues(json);

        try {
            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(onlyValues);
            BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(stringReader);
            String line;
            while ((line = bufReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.endsWith(",")) {
                    line = line.substring(0, line.length() - 1);
                }
                if (line.startsWith("\"") && line.endsWith("\"")) {
                    line = line.substring(1, line.length() - 1);
                }


                line = line.trim();
                if (line.length() > 0) {
                    values.add(line);
                }
                
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.warn("Unable to read lines in String:" + onlyValues);
        }

        return values;
    }
```