# How to extract a specific link in a json file

Tags: java, json

```
"papers": [
{
  "files": [
    {
      "url": "http://farnsworth.papro.org.uk/file/977", 
      "type": "Initial XML version of the paper", 
      "name": "c6938201-dac0-4ef9-91cd-ca6e8c30f4b8.xml"
    }, 
    {
      "url": "http://farnsworth.papro.org.uk/file/978", 
      "type": "Final annotated XML file", 
      "name": "c6938201-dac0-4ef9-91cd-ca6e8c30f4b8_final.xml"
    }
  ]
```

How can i get the first `url` in this json file ? What I have so far is:

```
                JSONObject file = (JSONObject) files.get(j);

                String url = (String) file.get("url");
                System.out.println(url);
```

Comment: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: Aside from "Don't use that ancient crufty json.org library" there are *numerous* examples of parsing JSON in Java here on SO that would get you further than you are.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332611/how-do-i-extract-value-from-json?rq=1 ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939250/parsing-json-file-java?lq=1 would also be of interest.

Comment: currently am getting the two url but i can't figure out how to get just the first url in the file. I don't know if there is something like `.first()`?

Comment: I have carefully examine all this links before posting this question, but none seems to have an answer to my question.

Comment: you can fetch this files object as a JSONArray instead of JSONObject.
The advantage being that, you get array.get(index) method for the JSONArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should work :

```
JSONArray results = d.getJSONArray("files");
JSONObject p = (JSONObject)results.get(0);
url = p.getString("url");
```