# JSON file parsing in java

Tags: java, json

Edited. Anyone know how to read the record in every new line. The below code can only read 1 sentence.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try
    {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("src/test.json"));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
        System.out.println(name);



    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939250/parsing-json-file-java

Comment: You can use any JSON parsing libs like [Jackson](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-streaming-api-to-read-and-write-json/).

Comment: I followed the download here link and it is a zip file and add external library to eclipse but still have error after inserting
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

Comment: please post your json file, thing is once you have got the jsonobject then you need to iterate/fetch from the object based on your json structure.

Answer (score 1):

[Many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939250/parsing-json-file-java). I suggest you use [google-gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use codehouse jackson

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tweets));
Map<String, Object> json_as_map = mapper.readValue(br, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
```

After that you can traverse your map or arraylist according to ur structure.

Comment: You have to add http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-jaxrs/1.9.12/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.12.jar in your classpath.
And then use JAVA Collection APIs to parse JSON.