# How to find Chrome download path in Java

Tags: java, google-chrome, download, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to write a test with Webdriver by using Chrome browser, I want to download some file, when I click download link, the file is being downloaded automatically to download folder.
I was wondering if there is some way to find out what is the current path of the download folder (Win / Linux)
Is there some configuration file where Chrome keep it settings ?

Thans

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google chrome is maintaining one config file for such custom configuration Named as **Preferences** which is in **JSON** format.So you have to read this file.You will get the current path of download folder from this file.

```
"download": {
      "default_directory": "CURRENT_PATH_OF_YOUR_DOWNLOAD_FOLDER",
      "directory_upgrade": true,
      "extensions_to_open": "",
      "prompt_for_download": false
 },
```

[Parsing JSON File Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939250/parsing-json-file-java?lq=1)
This will help you to read that file.

Location of this configuration file
In Linux is
**/USER_HOME_FOLDER/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences**
and in Windows is
**C:\Users\USER_ACCOUNT\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences**