# How to get the chrome browser download folder path from selenium?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium

I am trying to automate a script in c# selenium which downloads an excel file in chrome browser.Then I need to open the downloaded file to verify data.I cannot use the default local downloaded path of my computer as the download path might change in other systems.Can any one one tell me how to get the chrome download folder path in c# selenium.

Thanks,
Sharmila

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download file at custom path using Selenium WebDriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33434443/download-file-at-custom-path-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Thank u but I do not want to change the download path. I want to get the existing  download path in chrome

Comment: I believe the answer you're looking for is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437816/how-to-find-chrome-download-path-in-java

Answer (score 3):

You can get the `Downloads` path as follow:

```
    string pathUser = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
    string pathDownload = Path.Combine(pathUser, "Downloads");
```

Comment: This is a Windows setting that Chrome uses as default, but can be changed in Chrome (i.e. Chrome download folder may be different from "Windows" download folder)

Comment: Yes but i think the selenium webdriver for chrome will use default settings that's why I posted this.