# WebDriver: How to get/read the current instance target download directory

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I don't want to set any preferences on the driver itself, I just need for a specific test to grab the location of a recently saved file.

Any ideas on how i can do this?

Comment: Was the 'recently saved file' auto-downloaded?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: In Windows, any file auto-downloaded is stored in the default downloads folder of the user which can be accessed using: `File dirMyDownloads = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Downloads/");`
is this what you needed?

Comment: Not quite..... Our test CI has tests running on a number of jenkins machines. They run using randomly generated users, and startup scripts overwrite a number of env. variables. I need a deterministic way to grab the target location from webdriver itself maybe? Or any suggestion on aproach. I already did it by assuming the location is /downloads/, it works fine on my machine, but it does not work on Jenkins....

Comment: In that case, if you are using Chome in any of your tests, you should access the preferences JSON file. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18438722/904375