# How update the values using http put method asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am new to android and i am trying to update these values and it should be `HttpPut` method. I know only GET and POST method please anyone can guide me to convert this to PUT method. Now it is in `POST` method

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

json.put("Id", "15");
json.put("LId", EnId);
json.put("Name",assetname);
json.put("Des",Description1);


HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
jsonObj = json.toString();

httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonObj));
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Comment: Since you are new to android; I would recommend you to use volley. It handles all your network related issues by itself and is extremely fast.Follow https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html. You can make all sorts of requests using volley.

Comment: Thanks and can u convert above code to httpput method..?

Comment: You can find many such answers on Stack overflow. eg .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432885/http-put-request. If your problem is solved; kindly upvote

Comment: I am not getting Please can u edit my code to PUT

Comment: I dont think you got to change anything more than `HttpPost` to `HttpPut`

Comment: Yes but it is showing status code 405

Comment: I think your Rest service doesnt allow `PUT`. See more about [405](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html)