# How to decode an array of array elements in Android

Tags: android, arrays, json

A PHP script is sending to an Android app some data in the following format

```
[{"event_id":"4","message":"test"},["person1","person2"]]
```

I want to exact the 2 elements from this array into other arrays so I can easily manipulate the data. I got to the point in which the above response from the server is being converted into as string. What I can't seem to be able to do is to parse the data into arrays. I'm trying something on the following lines:

> ```
> receivedData = new JSONArray(result); //result is the string response from the server  
> JSONArray array1= receivedData.getJSONArray(0);  
> JSONArray array2= receivedData.getJSONArray(1);  
> int len = array1.length();
> ```

but `len`is not giving me back anything :(
What am I doing wrong and how could I change it.
Many thanks

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2255296/377628).

Answer (score 1):

What if you start by invoking new JSONObject(result); and then pulling an array out of that? I suspect you're trying to pull an array out of something that is not an array. Your PHP should not return something wrapped in [ ] it should return it wrapped in { }... also I believe your third JSON element (the array itself) is just hanging about without a label, which I believe is illegal.

so... 
if your php produced this:

```
 {"event_id":"4","message":"test"},"people": ["person1","person2"]}
```

and your java was this:

```
JSONObject j = new JSONObject(result);

String [] people = j.getJSONArray("people");
```

I believe you'd have what you are after.