# How can I take the elements in a Json array and put the contents in an arraylist?

Tags: java, json, arraylist

First off I just want to say I'm a beginner and any help I can get would be great.

I created a car class in a form application. Each car has three propertes: spaceNum, make, and model.

I'm storing each car into an an arraylist. Before exiting the program I write the contents of the arraylist to a file named save.json.

The contents are as follows:

> [{"spaceNum":"2","make":"b","model":"b"},{"spaceNum":"3","make":"c","model":"c"},{"spaceNum":"4","make":"d","model":"d"},{"spaceNum":"1","make":"a","model":"a"}]

As you can see there are four Cars stored in my arraylist.

My question is - How can I get the array from my save.json file, where I can then try to put it back into an arraylist?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255220/how-to-parse-a-json-and-turn-its-values-into-an-array

Comment: You should look into [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) or [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for converting back and forth from JSON to Java objects.

Answer (score 0):

I use [jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) for all my json serialization, so assuming you have a Car class, you can do something like this.

```
List<Car> cars = new ObjectMapper().readValue(new File("save.json"), TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, Car.class);
```

Comment: Thanks I installed the Jackson library. Hopefully it works. Thank you.