# Java convert special string to array of array

Tags: java, string

I want to split this string

```
['1','BR_1142','12,345','01-02-2012', 'Test 1'],['2','BR_1142','12,345','01-02-2012', 'Test 2']
```

To an array of array string in java?

Can I do it with regex or should I write a recursive function to handle this purpose?

Comment: Why you want to use Regex, if you can do it with simple `split`??

Comment: i want to have an array of array for example for this string array[1][2] should give me BR_1142. I don't know how can i do it with split? thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to test this because of recent crash wiped out all my programs, but I believe you can use the JSON parsers to parse the string. You might have to wrap it in `[` and `]` or `{` and `}` before you parse.

See

- http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/257-how-to-parse-json-in-java/
- http://www.json.org/java/
- [How to parse a JSON and turn its values into an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255220/how-to-parse-a-json-and-turn-its-values-into-an-array)

Comment: Thanks for your help I did it with JSON ObjectMapper

Answer (score 2):

How about something like the following

```
String str= "['1','BR_1142','12,345','01-02-2012', 'Test 1'],['2','BR_1142','12,345','01-02-2012', 'Test 2']";

String[] arr = str.split("\\],\\[");
String[][] arrOfArr = new String[arr.length][];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arrOfArr[i] = arr[i].replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");
}
```

Comment: @AKZ, you're right. You could try `split("','")` though that would also remove the `'` chars. I'm sure you can find an approach from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
String yourString = "['1','BR_1142','12,345','01-02-2012', 'Test 1'],['2','BR_1142','12.345','01-02-2012', 'Test 2']";
yourString = yourString.substring(1, yourString.lastIndexOf("]"));
String[] arr = yourString.split("\\],\\[");

String[][] arr1 = new String[arr.length][];
int i = 0;
String regex = "(?<=['],)";   // This regex will do what you want..
for(String a : arr) {
    arr1[i++] = a.split(regex);
}

for (String[] arrasd: arr1) {
    for (String s: arrasd) {
        System.out.println(s.replace(",", ""));
    }
}
```

Comment: @AKZ.. Also, if you try to retain `,` in between `12,345` from the above process, you will loose the other `'`.. So, I have replaced them with "" to remove them completely..

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String.split` and regex [look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in combination:

```
String str = "['1','BR_1142','12,345','01-02-2012', 'Test 1'],['2','BR_1142','12,345','01-02-2012', 'Test 2']";
String[] outerStrings = str.split("(?<=]),");
String[][] arrayOfArray = new String[outerStrings.length][];

for (int i=0; i < outerStrings.length; i++) {
   String noBrackets = outerStrings[i].substring(1, outerStrings[i].length() - 1);
   arrayOfArray[i] = noBrackets.split(",");
}
```