# How to convert String containing Array into an Array

Tags: java, arrays, string

This might have been asked before, but I spent some time looking, so here's what I have.
I have a string containing an array:

`'["thing1","thing2"]'`

I would like to convert it into an *actual* array:

`["thing1","thing2"]`

How would I do this?

Comment: make use of regex to parse the contents of string and then insert them into array

Comment: or you can use json deserialize

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Java convert special string to array of array - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652135/java-convert-special-string-to-array-of-array) (I voted as too bload before searching...)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a loop that runs through the whole string, checking for indexes of quotes, then deleting them, along with the word. I'll provide an example:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while(theString.indexOf("\"") != -1){
    theString = theString.substring(theString.indexOf("\"")+1, theString.length());
    list.add(theString.substring(0, theString.indexOf("\"")));
    theString = theString.substring(theString.indexOf("\"")+1, theString.length());
}
```

I would be worried about an out of bounds error from looking past the last quote in the String, but since you're using a String version of an array, there should always be that "]" at the end. But this creates only an ArrayList. If you want to convert the ArrayList to a normal array, you could do this afterwards:

```
String[] array = new String[list.size()];
for(int c = 0; c < list.size(); c++){
    array[c] = list.get(c);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using `replace` and `split` methods of `String` class, e.g.:

```
String s = "[\"thing1\",\"thing2\"]";
String[] split = s.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
```

Comment: Seems fragile. What if there are escaped special characters in the strings? Better to use a JSON parser.