# Android HttpPost is downloading wrong SSL cerficate

Tags: android, ssl

So, on my site, I use a couple different SSL cerficates. One for the root domain "illution.dk" and one for my subdomain "ci.illution.dk". Trouble is, when I fire a post request using  HttpPost, and I request a URL like "https://ci.illution.dk/login/device", it just throws an error message saying:

```
10-04 18:35:13.100: W/System.err(1680): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <ci.illution.dk> != <www.illution.dk> OR <www.illution.dk> OR <illution.dk>
```

I think this means that it is downloading the certificate of illution.dk, and then seeing that it does not support ci.illution.dk. However, everything is fine when I load up the browser and browse to "https://ci.illution.dk". My Android code is as follows:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        //appContext.getString(R.string.base_url)
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://ci.illution.dk/login/device");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", params[0]));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", params[1]));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            return response;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.d("ComputerInfo", "Error while loggin in: ClientProtocolException");
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("ComputerInfo", "Error while loggin in: IOException");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ComputerInfo", "Error while loggin in");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that it is an error with HttpPost, because if I use the code linked [here](http://digitallibraryworld.com/?p=189) it just works. I have modified the code to suit my specific needs, but here is my code: (Just in case the link goes down)

```
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

//do this wherever you are wanting to POST
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection conn;

    try{
    //if you are using https, make sure to import java.net.HttpsURLConnection
    url=new URL("https://ci.illution.dk/login/device");

    //you need to encode ONLY the values of the parameters
    String param="username=" + URLEncoder.encode("usernametest","UTF-8")+
    "&password="+URLEncoder.encode("passwordtest","UTF-8");

    conn=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    //set the output to true, indicating you are outputting(uploading) POST data
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    //once you set the output to true, you don't really need to set the request method to post, but I'm doing it anyway
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

    //Android documentation suggested that you set the length of the data you are sending to the server, BUT
    // do NOT specify this length in the header by using conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", length);
    //use this instead.
    conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(param.getBytes().length);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    //send the POST out
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    out.print(param);
    out.close();

    //build the string to store the response text from the server
    String response= "";

    //start listening to the stream
    Scanner inStream = new Scanner(conn.getInputStream());

    //process the stream and store it in StringBuilder
    while(inStream.hasNextLine())
        response+=(inStream.nextLine());

        Log.d("Test", response);
    }

    //catch some error
    catch(MalformedURLException ex){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ex.toString(), 1 ).show();

    }
    // and some more
    catch(IOException ex){

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ex.toString(), 1 ).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just look at the code at the following you would get the answer. I have used it in my code. You have to use in your code.

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String line = null;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

sb.append(line + "\n");}

is.close();

Take a look at following example i have used in it

```
    ArrayList<DailyExpDto> list = new ArrayList<DailyExpDto>();
    List<NameValuePair> qparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", "" + date));
    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", ""
            + Myapplication.getuserID()));

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(null, -1),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("YOURUSRNAME", "YOURPASSWORD"));
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url + "daily_expenditure.php?");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(qparams));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }
    // convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();

        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    Log.v("log", result);
    JSONObject jobj = null;
    try {
        jobj = new JSONObject(result);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    try {

        JSONArray JArray_cat = jobj.getJSONArray("category");
        JSONArray JArray_desc = jobj.getJSONArray("description");
        JSONArray JArray_exp = jobj.getJSONArray("expenditure");
        for (int i = 0; i < JArray_cat.length(); i++) {
            DailyExpDto dto = new DailyExpDto();
            dto.category = JArray_cat.getString(i);
            dto.desc = JArray_desc.getString(i);
            dto.exp = JArray_exp.getInt(i);
            list.add(dto);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what does it do?