# How to get data as an json array from a server and convert it in to java array to use in android application

Tags: java, android, json

> **Possible duplicate**
>
> [How to parse a JSON and turn its values into an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255220/how-to-parse-a-json-and-turn-its-values-into-an-array)

```
[
   [
      "sn1",
      "Liquid_level",
      "85"
   ],
   [
      "sn2",
      "Liquid_level,Temperature",
      "95"
   ],
   [
      "sn2",
      "Liquid_level,Temperature",
      "50"
   ],
   [
      "sn3",
      "Liquid_level",
      "85.7"
   ],
   [
      "sn4",
      "Liquid_level",
      "90"
   ],
   [
      "sn5",
      "Volt_meter",
      "4.5"
   ],
   [
      "sn6",
      "Temperature",
      "56"
   ],
   [
      "sn8",
      "Liquid_level",
      "30"
   ]
]
```

This is the data i want to get to a java array (to create a dynamic table to show data).

i can get a text value using this

```
String response = null;
            try {
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://test.tester.com/check.php", postParameters);
                String res=response.toString();}
```

Comment: You've got to provide way more information. What software is running on your server? Do you have control over the application? If so you can control what it sends to clients by way of output and go from there…

Comment: I'm getting a json array using a php script. i want to get this json array to the android application and convert it to a java array. If you can help that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255220/how-to-parse-a-json-and-turn-its-values-into-an-array

Comment: I'm writing you an answer using the GSON library, hold a sec...

Comment: I found the exact solution i need from this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/  Thank you very much Mr. Ravi Tamada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As from [How to parse a JSON and turn its values into an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255220/how-to-parse-a-json-and-turn-its-values-into-an-array):

> for your example:
>
> ```
> {'profiles': [{'name':'john', 'age': 44}, {'name':'Alex','age':11}]}
> ```
>
> you will have to do something of this effect:
>
> ```
> JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject(the_json);
> JSONArray the_json_array = myjson.getJSONArray("profiles");
> ```
>
> this returns the array object.
>
> Then iterating will be as follows:
>
> ```
>     int size = the_json_array.length();
>     ArrayList<JSONObject> arrays = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
>     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
>       JSONObject another_json_object = the_json_array.getJSONObject(i);
>             //Blah blah blah...
>             arrays.add(another_json_object);
>     }
>
> //Finally
> JSONObject[] jsons = new JSONObject[arrays.size()];
> arrays.toArray(jsons);
>
> //The end...
> ```
>
> You will have to determine if the data is an array (simply checking
>   that `charAt(0)` starts with `[` character).
>
> Hope this helps.

Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/users/251173/the-elite-gentleman

Answer (score 1):

first parse this json array and store in ArrayList

```
              try 
             {
                      ArrayList<String> arl= new ArrayList<String>();
                      JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(signedData);
                      JSONArray jroot = jobj.getJSONArray("xxxxx");

              for(int i=0;i<jroot.length();i++)
              {

                  JSONObject jElement = jroot.getJSONObject(i);

                  arl.add(jElement.getString("xxxxx"));


              }


          }

          catch (Exception e)
          {
               Log.v("log", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());

          }
```

and then using forloop store to string Array..

Comment: can you explain the JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(signedData); part

Answer (score 1):

Your conversion of JSON to Java largely depends on which library you are using to perform the task. The other answers here use the `org.json` library, but most geeks will react violently over its usage because it's quite slow. The fastest library I know of is Jackson, but I personally prefer Google-GSON because it's fast enough and yet remains very easy to use.

Looking at your sample string, you seem to have an array of arrays of strings. In Gson, you want to think of them as a `Collection` of a `Collection` of `String`s. Here's the sample code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Collection;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // your sample JSON string, converted to a java string
        String json = "[\n   [\n      \"sn1\",\n      \"Liquid_level\",\n      \"85\"\n   ],\n   [\n      \"sn2\",\n      \"Liquid_level,Temperature\",\n      \"95\"\n   ],\n   [\n      \"sn2\",\n      \"Liquid_level,Temperature\",\n      \"50\"\n   ],\n   [\n      \"sn3\",\n      \"Liquid_level\",\n      \"85.7\"\n   ],\n   [\n      \"sn4\",\n      \"Liquid_level\",\n      \"90\"\n   ],\n   [\n      \"sn5\",\n      \"Volt_meter\",\n      \"4.5\"\n   ],\n   [\n      \"sn6\",\n      \"Temperature\",\n      \"56\"\n   ],\n   [\n      \"sn8\",\n      \"Liquid_level\",\n      \"30\"\n   ]\n]";

        // instantiate a Gson object
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        // define the type of object you want to use it in Java, which is a collection of a collection of strings
        Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Collection<String>>>(){}.getType();

        // happiness starts here
        Collection<Collection<String>> stringArrays = gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);

        // simply print out everything
        for (Collection<String> collection : stringArrays) {
            for (String s : collection) {
                System.out.print(s + ", ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
sn1, Liquid_level, 85, 
sn2, Liquid_level,Temperature, 95, 
sn2, Liquid_level,Temperature, 50, 
sn3, Liquid_level, 85.7, 
sn4, Liquid_level, 90, 
sn5, Volt_meter, 4.5, 
sn6, Temperature, 56, 
sn8, Liquid_level, 30,
```

This is taken from the Google-GSON user guide: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples

Comment: You're free to pick a chosen answer if it did any help. :)