# JSONArray to Spinner

Tags: android, json, android-actionbar, android-spinner

I have a problem. I don't set JSONArray to Spinner. My JSON look `["category1","category2","category3"]`
How to get this JSONArray to spinner? I don't know if my code is well

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    String urlCat = "http://tvapp.pcrevue.sk/categories.json";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

         JSONArray jsonArray = getJSONArrayFromUrl(urlCat);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerMenu = new ArrayAdapter<String>(actionBar.getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, jsonArray);
        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(spinnerMenu, 
                new ActionBar.OnNavigationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
                        FragmentTransaction tx = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        switch (itemPosition) {
                        case 0:
                            tx.replace(android.R.id.content, new Tab1Fragment());
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            tx.replace(android.R.id.content, new Tab2Fragment());
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                        }
                        tx.commit();
                        return false;
                    }
                });
    }

    public JSONArray getJSONArrayFromUrl(String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        JSONArray jObj = null;
        String json = "";
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                //json += line;
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONArray(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

I need your help.
Thx

Answer (score 2):

I don't find any constructor in ArrayAdapter that Accepts JSONArray object, if you have any doubt refer [Array Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).

You need to pass the List instead of JSONArray.
And also,
**You are peforming network operation of the UI thread**, so you'll get **NetworkOnMainThread** exception. It will be ok for the lower versions but the heigher version will throw exception. Try using **AsyncTask** to get the values or a **Separate Thread**

So get the list like this

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    list.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
}
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerMenu = new ArrayAdapter<String>(actionBar.getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
```

Answer (score 1):

**First solution**

Actually I did not find any constructor in ArrayAdapter that needs JSONArray.
If your `JSONArray` is having all string elements then

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        List<String> listist = new ArrayList<String>();

        String res = callGet("http://tvapp.pcrevue.sk/categories.json");
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(res);

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                listist.add("" + jsonArray.get(i));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Log.e("", "listist.size() : " + listist.size());

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String callGet(String urlString) {

    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 10000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 10000);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
    HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urlString);

    try {

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }
}
}
```

I got my logcat output

```
03-17 21:49:36.821: E/(376): listist.size() : 10
```

**Second solution**

Have you tried [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) lib for json parsing? It convert Java Objects into their `JSON` representation.

```
List<String> listist = new ArrayList<String>();
iidList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, List.class);

ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerMenu = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            actionBar.getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listist);
```

Answer (score 0):

Spinners have no problem accepting arrays. So simply extract a java array from your json and pass that array to the spinner. There are many examples online for how to turn json into java array, such as [How to parse a JSON and turn its values into an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255220/how-to-parse-a-json-and-turn-its-values-into-an-array). And for creating spinner with java array: [Android: Create spinner programmatically from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784081/android-create-spinner-programmatically-from-array)

Comment: How to extract array from json ??

Comment: Notice that my response gives you two links. one for json to array and one for array to spinner. It the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255220/how-to-parse-a-json-and-turn-its-values-into-an-array is not sufficient, you can look it up on google and check out other resources.