# How to get all the product categories from the mysql db via php and return json array

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have an android app.
I want to send a get request to the get_categories.php file.
In the get_categories.php file I want to

```
$query_categories        = "SELECT category_name FROM categories";
```

and return all the categories found in that table into a json array.

How can I do that?

This is my incomplete code:

```
if (!empty($_GET)) {


    $query_categories        = "SELECT category_name FROM categories";
    $success = false;

    try{
        $sth = $connection->prepare($query_categories);
        //$sth->execute(array(':user_id' => $user_id));
        //$user_items_count = $sth->rowCount();  - these are lines from other php file I've used 

        foreach($)//??

        $success = true;
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = $ex;
        die(json_encode($response));
        $connection = null;
    }

    if($success) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Kylie";

        die(json_encode($response));
        $connection = null;      

    } else {
        $response["success"] = 2;
        $response["message"] = "something went wrong";
        die(json_encode($response));
        $connection = null;
    }

} else {
        $response["success"] = 3;
        $response["message"] = "Another brick in the wall";   
        echo json_encode($response);
        $connection = null;
}
```

Later on, in my Java code, how do I decode that?
Usually up until this point, in my other JSON transfers, I've received normal Json object with no arrays and read them this way:

```
setUserLastSeen(json.getString(TAG_USER_LAST_SEEN)); //for example.
```

But how do I decode an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For php side this how you can get the categories array  and make json,for prepared statements this is how you can accomplish

```
$success = false;
try {

  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
$success = true;
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
$response["data"]=null;
die(json_encode($response));
}

$query_categories = "SELECT category_name FROM categories";

try{

$sth = $sth->prepare($query_categories );
$success = true;

} catch(PDOException $e) {
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = 'Prepare failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
$response["data"]=null;
die(json_encode($response));
}

try{
$sth->execute();
$success = true;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = 'Execute failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
$response["data"]=null;
die(json_encode($response));
}

$categories = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);/* fetches all categories from db */

/* Output of $query_categories
Array
(
    [0] => cat1
    [1] => cat2
    [2] => cat3
    [3] => cat4
)
*/
/* json encode $query_categories 
["cat1","cat2","cat3","cat4"]
*/

/* check if categories exist or not*/
if(empty($categories)){
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No categories found";
        $response["data"]=null;
        die(json_encode($response));
        $connection = null; 

}

if($success) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Kylie";
    $response["data"]=$categories;
    die(json_encode($response));
    $connection = null;      
 /* output
 {"success":0,"message":"Kylie","data":["cat1","cat2","cat3","cat4"]}
 */
} else {
    $response["success"] = 2;/* don't where you are setting success to 2*/
    $response["message"] = "something went wrong";
    $response["data"]=null;
    die(json_encode($response));
    $connection = null;
}

} else {
        $response["success"] = 3;/* don't where you are setting success to 3*/
        $response["message"] = "Another brick in the wall";  
        $response["data"]=null; 
        die(json_encode($response));
        $connection = null;
}
```

I am not good at java but here is the reference [How to parse a JSON and turn its values into an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255220/how-to-parse-a-json-and-turn-its-values-into-an-array)

```
/* store json string in  the_json */
JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject(the_json);
JSONArray the_json_array = myjson.getJSONArray("data");
```

> **Note:** make sure on java side you must check the success from json which
>   must be ==1 and the_json_array is not null

[**PHP Data Objects**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 1):

you can use below code to ferch data using json and then decode that json array:

=================================================================================
                  try
            {

```
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("your webservice");

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse res = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            HttpEntity entity = res.getEntity();

            is = entity.getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            String line="0";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
            Log.d("Data",""+ result);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        String fd_ono=null;



        try
        {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data=null;

            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
            {
                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    fd_ono=json_data.getString("your column name");
                    textView.settext(fd_ono.toString());



            }


        }


        catch(JSONException e1)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Record not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```