# Converting a JavaScript Array that's been JSON.stringify to a Java Array

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, regex, json

Hello I'm trying to convert an Array which has been sent from my JavaScript after going through the `JSON.stringify` method. I'm currently experimenting/looking at a regex solution for it but anything that returns a normal JAVA `Array<Integer>` with the values between the "" works.

**JAVA Code:**

```
private ArrayList<Integer> convertJSONArrayStringtoArray(String jsonArrayString){


     Matcher m = Pattern.compile(".*\\\"(.*)\\\".*").matcher(jsonArrayString);
     while(m.find()) {
       System.out.println("convertJSONtoArray: " + m.group(1));    
     } 

    return null;

}
```

String Composition (Note that the string is not a JSON object that holds a array, just a simple array):

```
["12441","3324","11584","3337","25739","25810"]
```

Comment: There are plenty of JSON parser libraries available for Java.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255220/how-to-parse-a-json-and-turn-its-values-into-an-array

Comment: I disagree with duplicate question, this question is not the same the linked one. It is asking how to deserialise that js array which is not a valid JSON therefore you cannot deserialise via a JSON serialiser directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), you can do:

```
    List<String> result = new Gson().fromJson( jsonArrayString, List.class );
```

Answer (score 0):

It it is a one-shot and you feel using a whole library is overkill :

```
String input = "[\"12441\",\"3324\",\"11584\",\"3337\",\"25739\",\"25810\"]";
String[] tokens = input.substring(1, input.length()-2).split(",");
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(tokens).stream().map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.substring(1, s.length()-1))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```