# JSON array initialization using for loop

Tags: java, json

I am creating a RESTful web service in Java. There is an array of objects in my Java implementation that I need to pass to the client side via JSON.

I need to create an array of objects in JSON assigned by the Java objects array.

Can I use a `for loop` for this assignment? If I can, then what will the syntax be?

Comment: You can use Json library to create Json object

Comment: Look at this ;)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255220/how-to-parse-a-json-and-turn-its-values-into-an-array

Comment: Format your Question