# How to save json data in PostgreSQL using jQuery Post and Java?

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, postgresql

I would like to save my json data object into my Postgresql using jQuery(ajax call on post request) and Java after clicking Submit button, Please help me to do this ? Thanks in advance.

html:

```
(function() {
  var testValue;
  testValue = {};
  $('input[id=buttonId]').click(function() {
    var name;
    name = $(this).attr('name');
    testValue[name] = $(this).val();
  });
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    $('input[id=fileId]').each(function($i) {
      var name;
      name = $(this).attr('name');
      testValue[name] = $(this).val();
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(testValue));//it gives the json data object, after clicking on Submit button`[ex: {"firstButton":"button1","secondButton":"button2","file":"test.txt"} ]`
  });
})();
```

Postgresql table: `create table savedata(id integer primary key, content json);`

credentials:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname"
db.default.user=test
db.default.password=test
```

html:

```
<input type='button' value='button1' class='button' id="buttonId" name='firstButton'/>
<input type='button' value='button2' class='button' id="buttonId" name='secondButton'/>
<input type='file' name='file' id="fileId" value='file upload'/>
<input type='submit' value='submit' id='submit'>
```

Comment: Thanks @Thomas for reply, Yes, front-end can be either Javascript/AngularJS/jQuery and back-end is either Java/Scala and Postgresql database.

Comment: @Thomas There's nothing obscure about a javascript frontend with a java backend. In fact it's quite common.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by writing a [HTTP server](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html) in java which accepts POST requests from javascript later. You would be smart to also add some form of [authentication](http://oauth.net/2/) in it so not everybody can add records. You can also use a [framwork](http://restx.io/) which I would use.

As soon as a POST request comes in with JSON data and the required authorisation you can let Java parse the JSON to Insert statements for the database.

Now the Javascript part: you can best send JSON encoded data with ajax using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Use a POST request.

In this case it would look like
using:

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_java.htm
- [How to parse a JSON and turn its values into an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255220/how-to-parse-a-json-and-turn-its-values-into-an-array)
- http://restx.io/docs/ref-core.html

  ```
  // Create a method that handles a POST request. In this case to "/message"
  @POST("/message/}")
  public Message insertInDb(Message msg // body param
                          ) {
      // Decode the JSON to an array object so you can loop it for insert statement(s)           
     JSONArray json = new JSONArray(msg);
      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Create the postgre connection
    Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
       Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
       c = DriverManager
          .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb",
          "manisha", "123");
       c.setAutoCommit(false);
       System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

       stmt = c.createStatement();

       // Use the JSON data instead below for the INSERT statement:
       String sql = "INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) "
             + "VALUES (1, 'Paul', 32, 'California', 20000.00 );";
       stmt.executeUpdate(sql);


       stmt.close();
       c.commit();
       c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
     return  e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage();

    }
      return "success";
  }
  ```

jQuery

```
    //POST JSON data to the API
    $.post( "youdomain.com/message", JSON.stringify(yourDataObjectOrArray));
```