# Deserializing Json Object in java

Tags: javascript, java, json, object

I cannot figure it out, I should deserialize a json object of this type:

`{
    "value":integer",
    "total":1",
    "records":138",
    "rows":[
    {
        "value1":6,
        "value2":true,
        "bool":true,
        "floatNumber":140.41",
        "floatNumber2":28.7",
        "floatNumber3":140.41",
        "cssClassName":""",
        "date":"19/03/2022"",
        "UTCdate":"2016-03-22T00:00:00+0000"",
        "UTCdate2":"2016-03-24T20:45:25+0000"
    },
    {
        "value1":6,
        "value2":true,
        "bool":true,
        "floatNumber":140.41",
        "floatNumber2":28.7",
        "floatNumber3":140.41",
        "cssClassName":""",
        "date":"19/03/2022"",
        "UTCdate":"2016-03-22T00:00:00+0000"",
        "UTCdate2":"2016-03-24T20:45:25+0000"}
]}`

but I do not know how to do. I wish that this item was added to my class, pointing to what value to assign the corresponding property.

I tried to use Flexjson library but didn't saw any function that will let me what i want to do.

Where to start?

PS: I never serialized an object to JSON, so I do not know how it works.

Comment: Have you tried with Google GSON?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go through this tutorial. Hope it will help you.

1. [How to convert Java object to / from JSON (Jackson)](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)
2. https://dzone.com/articles/deserializing-json-java-object

Comment: I did that, and finally came to the solution. thanks! This video too helped me alot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PARyHhklbgc

Comment: first link has been updated:  https://mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Answer (score 3):

That's json. You need to parse it using api.

For example

```
{'profiles': [{'name':'john', 'age': 44}, {'name':'Alex','age':11}]}
```

you will have to do something of this effect:

```
 JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject(the_json);
 JSONArray the_json_array = myjson.getJSONArray("profiles");
```

this returns the array object.

Then iterating will be as follows:

```
int size = the_json_array.length();
ArrayList<JSONObject> arrays = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    JSONObject another_json_object = the_json_array.getJSONObject(i);
        //Blah blah blah...
        arrays.add(another_json_object);
}

//Finally
JSONObject[] jsons = new JSONObject[arrays.size()];
 arrays.toArray(jsons);
```

Example code is taken from [How to parse a JSON and turn its values into an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255220/how-to-parse-a-json-and-turn-its-values-into-an-array)

Answer (score -1):

Java or Javascript? You *do* know that these are 2 **completely different** languages?

In Javascript you do it like this:

```
// object to string:
JSON.stringify(object);

// string to object
JSON.parse(object);
```

Comment: It's a json created by javascript, but i need to deserialize it using java