# Parse repeated fields into objects

Tags: json, jackson

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "name1" : "Jon Smith",
  "age1" : 25,
  "name2" : "Mary Carter",
  "age2" : 31
}
```

I would like to deserialize it to the following Java structure:

```
public class PersonList {
  private Person person1;
  private Person person2;
}

public class Person {
  private String name;
  private int age;
}
```

Is it possible with Jackson?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure, but you can try to convert the json into an array, loop through the array like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length-1;i+=2){
    persons[i] = new Person(array[i],array[i+1]);
}
```

I know dinamic variables are not used in Java so I assumed you can use a vector (persons[])

Also , use this ([How to parse a JSON and turn its values into an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255220/how-to-parse-a-json-and-turn-its-values-into-an-array)) for converting JSON to array

Comment: Sorry, i want to use Jackson, and prefer not use manual parsing.

Comment: Try this link https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Comment: Please do not paste general information here, i know Jackson quite well... I want to achieve my specific case in the original post.