# How to get values from JSONObject in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, json, string, converters

I am trying to parse a JsonArray and get its values but I am gettign error when I use

```
   jitem.getString("firstitem");
```

or

```
  jitem.getJSONObject("firstitem");
```

or

```
 jitem.get("firstitem");
```

Following is the code snippet.

```
  JSONArray arr_items = new JSONArray(str); 
        if(arr_items!=null && arr_items.size()>0){

            for(int i=0;i<arr_items.size();i++){
            JSONObject jitem = arr_items.getJSONObject(i);//works fine till here
             jitem.getString("firstitem"); //throws exception here
            }
```

This is the JSONArray that I am parsing

```
 [{"firstitem":"dgfd","secondtitem":"dfgfdgfdg","thirditem":"fdgfdgdf@sjhasjkdsha.com","fourthitem":"jkksdjklsfjskj"}]
```

what I am doing wrong? How to get these values by using keys?

**Update:Note** This array and its parameters are not null at all. They all have valid values.

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: which json library are you using? Since you have mixed methods of org.json and org.json.simple

Comment: @SachinGupta I am using org.apache.commons.json

Comment: @Henry I am getting different exceptions on all three. On 'getString' system is throwing null value though the values are present. On 'get' I think (not sure, as I deleted logs)  it is saying soemthing about structure though structure is exactly what I mentioned in OP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255220/how-to-parse-a-json-and-turn-its-values-into-an-array   check this

Comment: @gladiator this is something different, link that you shared tells how to parse/convert JSONArray into JSONObject. I have already done it successfully, My problem is that I am unable to get value of individual item of JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

First check arr_items is not empty.
Then, try surrounding your snippet with try/catch :

```
try {
       your snippet

      } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem? It avoids an exception, but one still does not have the value.

Comment: In Android Studio if i don't surround with try/catch this type of snippet, the editor give an alert and i must surround it. So maybe, he can try

Answer (score 0):

Check below

```
String json ="{'array':" + "[{'firstitem':'dgfd','secondtitem':'dfgfdgfdg','thirditem':'fdgfdgdf@sjhasjkdsha.com','fourthitem':'jkksdjklsfjskj'}]"+ "}";
     JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray the_json_array = myjson.getJSONArray("array");

    int size = the_json_array.length();
//  ArrayList<JSONObject> arrays = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        JSONObject another_json_object = the_json_array.getJSONObject(i);
    //  arrays.add(another_json_object);
        System.out.println(another_json_object.get("firstitem"));
    }
```

it require some array name so appended array name to it , if you want without it you have to add GSON.