# How to fetch value of entity from JSON String

Tags: java, json

This is my Json String and I am trying to fetch the value of Entity.I am a beginner in using JSON.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "john",
        "preferences": [
            {
                "Entity": [
                    "IBM",
                    "Pfizer"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Topic": "Pharma"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Shilpa , what did you try. Did you look at JsonSimple , or GSON to parse this. Please try using them and parsing it.

Comment: If you search for JSON parsing, there are plenty of resources available.

Comment: Please try to explain what exactly your problem is? Are you trying to parse in by Android or any other technology?

Answer (score 0):

try as follow :

```
JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject(the_json_string);
JSONArray the_json_array = myjson.getJSONArray("profiles");
```

for more : [How to parse a JSON and turn its values into an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255220/how-to-parse-a-json-and-turn-its-values-into-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library. If your input is a JSON string, you first need to parse it using a `JsonParser` object which returns us a `JsonElement` which is converted into JsonArray as the input Json is an array. You then extract the first object from it using `get(0)` and then convert it into a `JsonObject`, extract `preferences` element as JsonArray and follow similar procedure to get `Entity`.

```
        String jsonString = "[" +
            "    {" +
            "        \"_id\": john," +
            "        \"preferences\": [" +
            "            {" +
            "                \"Entity\": [" +
            "                    IBM," +
            "                    Pfizer" +
            "                ]" +
            "            }," +
            "            {" +
            "                \"Topic\": Pharma" +
            "            }" +
            "        ]" +
            "    }" +
            "]";

    JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString).getAsJsonArray();

    JsonArray preferences = jsonArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("preferences").getAsJsonArray();
    JsonArray entity = preferences.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("Entity").getAsJsonArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.json.*;


JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(" .... ");
String pageName = obj.getJSONObject("pageInfo").getString("pageName");

JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("posts");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
    String post_id = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("post_id");
    ......
}
```

May be it may helps you: [Parse JSON in Java](http://theoryapp.com/parse-json-in-java/)