# Parse JSON in Android And Display It In String like array

Tags: android, json, android-json

I am A beginner at the android studio. I want to parse a JSON object and I want to display it like this.

```
String mNames[] = {"name1", "name2", "name3"};
```

How Can I do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **JSONObject** and **JSONArray** as displayed in the following example:

```
{'profiles': [{'name':'john', 'age': 44}, {'name':'Alex','age':11}]}

JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject(the_json);
JSONArray the_json_array = myjson.getJSONArray("profiles");

int size = the_json_array.length();
ArrayList<JSONObject> arrays = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    JSONObject another_json_object = the_json_array.getJSONObject(i);
        //Blah blah blah...
        arrays.add(another_json_object);
}

//Finally
JSONObject[] jsons = new JSONObject[arrays.size()];
String[] blah = arrays.toArray(jsons);
```

(Taken from [How to parse a JSON and turn its values into an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255220/how-to-parse-a-json-and-turn-its-values-into-an-array))

Also, just for your information, this process has nothing to do with Android Studio itself, rather with Java and JSON ^^